# Javascript code present in .aspx file not getting analysed with Javascript plugin of Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I want javascript code present in .aspx file to get analysed with Sonar.
I have installed javascript plugin and checked its not getting analysed.

Please let me know how can javascript code can be analysed if not present in the .js file

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.aspx` to the list of extensions that the Javascript plugin should analyze, by setting the property `sonar.javascript.file.suffixes` (either trough the SonarQube UI, or as a parameter to the MSBuild SonarQube Runner using the `/d:sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=...` syntax).

Note that in SonarQube, a file can be analyzed only by a single language plugin for now. This means that, if you decide to analyze `.aspx` files with the Javascript plugin, you will not be able to analyze them using the Web or CSS plugins for example.

Comment: I have tried that but still javascript code in the .aspx is not getting analysed

Comment: I have added .aspx to the extensions of javascript plugin but it gives parsing error at the script tag in which javascript code is there in  the .aspx file

Comment: Unfortunately JavaScript plugin is able to analyse only pure JS files so far.